# Xmonad focused window border issues with virtualbox/vmware guest additions

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtualization, vmware-fusion, xmonad

I've tested xmonad on ubuntu and archlinux, running either on virtualbox and vmware. After installing guest additions (and the equivalent vmware tools for vmware), the focus border stops working. I was just wondering if there was a workaround or if anyone has a similar setup working?

Comment: What are the guest-addition-tools? Is it a package that I did not find in my search for it?

Comment: @Robert Massaioli yes it's a package that allows your guests to go fullscreen, share the mouse and clipboard with the host, and to use the Shared folders, virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html

Comment: You're not alone in the world: I have exactly the same problem :-(

Comment: @NicholasWu If you're using osx as your host machine, you can use parallels which doesnt have the same issue.

Comment: [Could be (related to) this unregarded bug with `xserver-xorg-video-vmware` and `XSetWindowBorder`](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-vmware/+bug/312080)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research, I found that these steps resolved the issues for me.

```
sudo apt-get install xcompmgr
```

Then just run the following in a terminal (or whatever) that should be kept alive for the rest of your session:

```
xcompmgr
```

---

I just discovered this when blindly trying stuff from various blogs and the VirtualBox [ticket](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/6479). I'm having an OS X host and Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit guest.

Comment: Yes, a thousand times.  This worked for me :)

Comment: Thank you! I had rendering problems and artefacts, relating to window borders, running awesome wm under VMware, and xcompmgr solved everything.